# Treat warnings as failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to clean up my test suite and to make this easier I'd like to have rspec raise an error when ever it encounters a warning. Rather then pass the test and carry on, I'd like the test to fail. Is there a way I can configure rspec to do this?

Comment: I think you'll have to patch the underlying warning caller. At least I can't think of a way for Rspec to capture and raise automatically. I'd say you'll have to patch the target logger or even Kernel#logger to make sure you handle everything.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about deprecation warnings?  Or warnings in general?

I know you can raise errors when you hit deprecation warnings by setting `config.active_support.deprecation = :raise` in your `test.rb`

Comment: Warnings in general

Answer (score 0):

Per the RubyDoc for RSpec on [Method: RSpec::Matchers#output](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers%3Aoutput), you should be able to fail the test by using `expect(method).to_not output.to_stdout`. I'm no expert in using RSpec, but in theory that should work. RSpec-Puppet has a very similar functionality built in that fails on warnings by using `Puppet.expects(:warning).never` .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work everywhere, since there is no contract that warnings have to be issued through [Logger#warn](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-warn), but this might do a decent job.

```
class Logger
  def warn(*args)
    super
    if Rails.env.test?
      raise(RuntimeError, "failing upon warn")
    end
  end
end

log = Logger.new
log.warn("foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rspec gives us a simple way to do this globally:

```
config.before do
  expect_any_instance_of(Logger).to_not receive(:warn)
end
```